# Does matlab have some sort of data structure with different sized rows/columns or anything similar?

Tags: matlab, matrix, arraylist

For example a matrix with elements ( 1 2 3 ; 4 5 6 7)
Obviously this creates an error in matlab, but if I had to do this in java I would create an ArrayList> to hold these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a read about [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html). They do what you want and more.